# Override Border Colors & List items based on odd/even

Tags: material-ui, themes

inb4: I am totally new to material-ui.

Hi all,

I guess I have a bit of a weird question. I have a react application based on bootstrap and want to *slowly* migrate to material-ui.
Best case I can adapt the styling currently present for bootstrap in material-ui.
I started with adjusting the colors in the palette (createMuiTheme) and using this theme in every new component.
However, I can not figure out how to, for example, change the bg-color of a list item depending if it is odd or even numbered.
Also, can I change border-colors based on the theme? Do I need to use overrides for this? If so, is there a best-practice approach?

Apologies if this is documented somewhere.

Olli

edit:

my current theme looks like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
palette: {
    primary: {
        main: '#009afe' // primary color
    },
    secondary: {
        main: '#1a4361' // secondary color
    },
    error: {
        main: '#c72525' // error color
    },
    warning: {
        main: '#f89406' // warning color
    },
    info: {
        main: '#009afe' // primary color
    },
    success: {
        main: '#3a8e3a' // success color
    },
    background: {
        default: '#272b30', // third background color
        paper: '#1c1e22', // third background color
        secondary: '#272b30'
    },
    text: {
        primary: '#c8c8c8', // primary text color
        secondary: '#ffffff'
    }
},
typography: {
    fontSize: 20
},
overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
        '@global': {
            html: {
                WebkitFontSmoothing: 'auto'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I extended background to hold more values than one, but I honestly don't know if it's against the rules of material-design.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (I guess). My question was not.... smart:

How I "solved" it:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
palette: [...]
typography: [...]
overrides: {
    MuiListItem: {
        root: {
            backgroundColor: '#272b30' // primary bg color
        },
        button: {
            '&:nth-child(odd)': {
                backgroundColor: '#1c1e22' // third bg color
            },
            '&:nth-child(even)': {
                backgroundColor: '#202429' // fourth bg color
            },
            '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: '#3e444c !important' // fifth bg color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});